# Ember component constructor args is Proxy {}

Tags: ember.js

In a fresh Ember 3.20 project (also same in 3.19), after adding a new component.

application.hbs:

```
<Test @foo="hello" />
```

components/test.js:

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';

export default class TestComponent extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super(...arguments)
        console.log(this.args)
    }
}
```

Console: *Proxy {}*

How can I access this.args within the constructor?

Comment: You should be able to access `this.args.foo`. You may got confused by `this.args` being a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and therefore didn't seeing the values as you are used to from POJOs.

Comment: Yes ok that seems to work.  Also, I assume passing in a reference to a parent component with <Test @parent={{this}} /> than calling this.args.parent.args.foo in the constructor isn't supposed to work by design?  It does work in other functions/properties though.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's supported but it's bad practice for sure. You should only pass the required data and functions to a child component. Not the entire instance of the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

the args of a component is a Proxy so that special behavior can wrap accesses to the args.  For example, when you access one of the args -- only then will the arg be "consumed" and your getters/actions entangled with the state of that arg. This has the advantage of optimizing your change tracking by default, so if you pass 100 args, and only use one or two of them in your component, you don't have to pay the cost of those 100 args causing updates to your component.

It works kinda like this:

```
args = new Proxy(actualArgs, {
  get(target, argName) {
     consumeTag(tagFor(target, argName));

     return target[argName];
  }
});
```

Where, normally, if you only had a vanilla object, accessing the arg would only get you the value. This proxy demonstrates interaction with the tracking system so that your component can now be *entangled* with the arg's updates

For more information on autotracking, @pzuraq goes in to great depth here: https://www.pzuraq.com/how-autotracking-works/ (not necessarily auto-tracking in *ember*, but more *in general*)

Also, documentation on `Proxy`, if interested: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

---

*Note: this information is for Ember 3.13+*